# Detect the n-th duplication (and n+1-th,...) in a vector

Tags: r

Given a vector like:

```
x <- c("r", "r", "b", "b", "b", "b", "r", "r", "y", "y")
```

How can I detect the elements that represent the (at least) n-th duplication of a value?

For this case, if we do not want more than two duplications, this should give:

```
duplicatedN(x, 2)
# F, F, F, F, T, T, T, T, F, F
```

In other words:  An element `i` with value `v` should be labeled as TRUE if there are at least N previous elements with the same value `v`.

Comment: How about `x <- sort(x)
; rle(x)$values[rle(x)$lengths > 2]
; [1] "b" "r"` ?

Comment: It should respect the original order

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A possible solution using data.table :

```
library(data.table)

duplicatedN <- function(x,n=2){
  DT <- data.table(A=x)
  DT[,dup:=1:.N > n,by=A]
  return(DT$dup)
}

x <- c("r", "r", "b", "b", "b", "b", "r", "r", "y", "y")

> duplicatedN(x,1)
 [1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
> duplicatedN(x,2)
 [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
> duplicatedN(x,3)
 [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
> duplicatedN(x,4)
 [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

Comment: also, the `ave` equivalent should be `as.logical(ave(x, x, FUN = function(x) seq_along(x) > 2))`

Comment: @alexis_laz: that's great! you should post it as an answer... and thanks to your suggestion I noticed that I was using a useless ifelse ;)

Answer (score 1):

This solution around `table` does the job:

If you want to return a logical:

```
duplicateN <- function(x, n){
  x %in% names(which(table(x) >= n))
}

> duplicateN(x, 3)
[1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

Or if you directly want to return the actual elements:

```
atleastN <- function(x, n){
  x[x %in% names(which(table(x) >= n))]
}

# x[duplicateN(x, n)] would also work

> atleastN(x, 3)
[1] "r" "r" "b" "b" "b" "b" "r" "r"
```

Is this what you needed?

Comment: I think not. The first two 'r', for instance, should be labeled as FALSE (they are not N-duplicated yet)

Comment: ah I missed the "previous elements" part. Apparently you have something working provided by @digEmAll ;-)